# Battlefield 4 getting launched from Battlelog

Tags: battlefield-4

Seems that my Desktop Battlefield 4 app when opened, is first launching Battlelog in a browser window, then Battlelog is launching the Desktop session to join a game. What's all that about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **how** of this has been answered over at stack overflow.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995353/how-does-battlelog-launch-games-from-browser

As to the **why** of it, why one would do this instead of implementing a simple web control in their launcher, for any legitimate reason, I have no idea.

From a security perspective, it seems to be actually quite a bad idea for every game's launcher to tie itself into your browser. Without this tying: If the launcher code has a vulnerability, it's unlikely to be triggered because the server has to send a malformed response (usually the launcher opens the connection, as users tend to be behind NAT). With this tying on the other hand, if your browser used to access lots of websites contains 417 game launcher managers which may be running executable code with full access to the browser, well you can predict what that turns into once the blackhats get involved.

At the very least, it makes securing the system (for those interested in using the computer for more than just battlefield) if you don't trust this browser plugin quite a bit trickier. It would at minimum involve using multiple browsers.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! It seems they rolled it back to it's usual local launch. . . .